# Lucas Lehmer Primality Test

Tags: performance, c, primes, gmp

I have coded the [Lucas-Lehmer primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) following Wikipedia's description. I used the `mod 2^n - 1` suggested in the article but was wondering if there were any other improvements I could make. I am using the GMP library for arbitrary precision integers. The program asks an integer `n` as input, then checks every Mersenne number `M(i)` for all `i` less than `n`. `n = 10000` takes around 25 seconds on my computer.

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

_Bool mersenne_prime(unsigned long exponent) {
    mpz_t sequence, number, temp;
    // Intialize variables
    mpz_init_set_ui(sequence, 4);
    mpz_init(temp);
    // Set number to 2^n - 1
    mpz_init_set_ui(number, 1);
    mpz_ui_pow_ui(number, 2, exponent);
    mpz_sub_ui(number, number, 1);
    // Repeat exponent-2 times
    for (unsigned long counter = exponent; --counter - 1;) {
        mpz_mul(sequence, sequence, sequence);
        // Modulus suggested by wikipedia
        while (mpz_cmp(sequence, number) > 0) {
            // Most significant bits of sequence
            mpz_div_2exp(temp, sequence, exponent);
            // Least significant bits of sequence
            mpz_mod_2exp(sequence, sequence, exponent);
            mpz_add(sequence, sequence, temp);
        }
        // Erratic case
        if (mpz_cmp(number, sequence) == 0) {
          mpz_set_ui(sequence, 0);
        }
        mpz_sub_ui(sequence, sequence, 2);
    }
    // sequence == 0 means prime
    _Bool result = mpz_sgn(sequence) == 0;
    // Clear variables
    mpz_clears(sequence, number, temp, NULL);
    return result;
}

int main() {
    mpz_t num;
    unsigned long limit;
    mpz_init_set_ui(num, 3);
    // Get limit
    scanf("%lu", &limit);
    printf("Searching for Mersenne primes...\nM2 is prime!\n");
    while (mpz_cmp_ui(num, limit) < 0) {
        unsigned long num_ui = mpz_get_ui(num);
        if (mersenne_prime(num_ui)) {
            printf("M%lu is prime!\n", num_ui);
        }
        mpz_nextprime(num, num);
    }
    // Clear num
    mpz_clear(num);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [GMP code on RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Lucas-Lehmer_test#GMP) is about 2x faster if you're looking for performance improvements.

It has a reasonable number of comments explaining the various optimizations.  Most of the help will be in the pre-tests, where we know easy ways to find out if the result will be composite.  The test itself is not too dissimilar, with a few different choices made.

I don't particularly like your for loop, which you wrote more like a while loop -- mixing the iteration and test together.

Comment: While this answer is welcome, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the linked resource, so that the answer is complete in itself, and still valuable when the link target changes or disappears.  I suggest you [edit] to incorporate relevant suggestions (with samples if you can).  Also, could you you be more specific with your final comment?  Perhaps you can show a clearer way to write the loop.